# Stripping special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following string contains characters outside of the normal ASCII set:

```
var myNewStr = "<p>.  Total distance: 60 miles.</p>";
```

How do I strip out characters, so I don't get the following error:

```
var myNewStr = "<p>.
           ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

In a hex editor, the hex values for these characters are E2 80 A8

Comment: Is it only error that you receiving? And did you copied full error line? It seems that error not exactly what you thinking.

Comment: What is the `strip`? Did you implement it by yourself?

Comment: I forgot to remove the function strip that I wrote for this (which didn't work).

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution is to use node.js Buffer:

`const strippedString = Buffer.from(someString, 'utf8').toString('ascii');`

Comment: When I do this I get: Total distance: 60 miles.</p>";
       ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: You are right, my code example was incorrect, I modified it. The problem is that the string you provide ('<p>.  Total distance: 60 miles.</p>') is not a valid JS String. So there is no way this string will arise in your code as a value of a variabale. If you read it from file then you can read it in binary mode and receive a Buffer, then convert it to string.

Answer (score 0):

vsenko is right, this is not a valid javascript string and can't arise in code, even as a comment!

I was reading this string in as a file then setting a variable to whatever was in the file. I needed to do some manipulation of the file to strip out this special character. The character was E2-80-A8 (U+2028, LINE SEPARATOR). This would cause the javascript string to have a new line and javascript doesn't support multiline.

The code I used to strip out occurrences of this line separator was:

```
 str = str.replace(/[\u2028]/g,'');
```